# C++ Reading double values into a 2D array from a file containing both strings and doubles

Tags: c++, arrays, string, double

I'm working through a program where I have an input file containing state names, and three separate taxes for each state: sales tax, property tax, and income tax. I'm attempting to read the tax values (read as double variables) into an array of type double. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double a = 0,
       b = 0,
       c = 0;
   double array[5][3];
   string state_name;
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open("test.dat");

   for (; fin >> state_name >> a >> b >> c;)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {
             fin >> array[i][j];
             cout << array[i][j] << "\t";
           }
           cout << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the data file:

```
    TEXAS        .0825 .02  -.03
    CALIFORNIA   .065  .04   .05
    MARYLAND     .03   .025  .03
    MAINE        .095  .055  .045
    OHIO         .02   .015  .02
```

And from the this, the program outputs the array, except that each position reads -9.25596e+061. I was wondering if this was because the program was trying to read the string into the array. I was also wondering if there was a way to overlook the string in the file line by line so that only the double values are read into the array.

Comment: You should use `while(fin >> state_name >> a >> b >> c)` instead of the for loop. Your meaning is clearer that way.

Answer (score 0):

You read in the entire line in the `for` loop. You don't need to do `fin >> array[i][j]` later. Instead you should be doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    fin >> state_name;
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        fin >> array[i][j];
        cout << array[i][j] << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;

    if(!fin)
    {
         // handle an error reading the file
    }
}
```

Comment: I adjusted the code to include `fin >> state_name;` and the program ran most of the file, but didn't output `.0825 .02  -.03` for Texas. Also, the last row in the array is still `-9.25596e+061`, but the other values went through fine. I wonder if there's something else going on here.

Comment: You misunderstood my replacement code. The code above should replace your entire `for (; fin >> state_name >> a >> b >> c;) { ... }` loop

Comment: Has something like this ever been done inside a for-read loop? Or, would it have been possible to do the same thing in a for-read loop?

Comment: You could do it as a for loop if you look at pbarmettler's answer. You could replace his while loop with `for(; fin >> state_name >> array[row][0] >> array[row][1] >> array[row][2]; ) { ++row; }` but it would be a little weird to use a for loop like that. Nothing technically wrong with it though.

Comment: Understood. Either way, your input's helped me out. I definitely understand it better now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double array[5][3];
    string state_name;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("test.dat");

    // Read the file row by row
    int row =0;
    while(fin >> state_name >> array[row][0] >> array[row][1] >> array[row][2]) {
       ++row;
    }

    // Print the result
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           cout << array[i][j] << "\t";
       }
       cout << endl;
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

If you allow me to think one step further, you probably prefer to push each row into a vector rather than a static array. Otherwise you need to rewrite your code if the file will have more than 5 rows.